# Confused on what's what because of my teacher.

Tags: css, dreamweaver

Okay, so the problem is that i do not know what he has done. It all seemed confusing. I have three boxes and they have a gray over lay at the top which is fine. The problem is all i can do is change the colour of it. I would like a gradient.

[Code for gradient](http://www.css3factory.com/linear-gradients/)

What the website looks like. (Note - I am talking about the three boxes which the earth picture)

[Code](http://gyazo.com/f5e50b08ad34512ad4e6d192be3695e7)

Also i do have a roll over animation but that works fine.

Thank you for any help! Much appreciated!

Comment: The website http://gyazo.com/b0fd375d943bffe7ff791b62d37306c9

Comment: Please edit the question and post the relevant code there, in the question itself. Don't forget to format it as code and make an actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Css and add `background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #11577A 0%, #2B729F 100%);` in the class of the title. 
syntax is `background: linear-gradient(direction, color-stop1, color-stop2, ...);` the tags -o- represent the useragent and there are more useragents too like -webkit- -ms- -moz- which are useful in case of chrome, ie, and mozilla firefox respectively.

Comment: Thank you, i have just noticed i was looking at the wrong [art of the code the whole time. He moved some code to the the bottom. Thank you for this though! Taught me a new thing or two.